# KnockoutJS push object onto array inside an object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Can someone tell me why this is not working?

```
function Event() {
    self.EventName = ko.observable();
    self.EventTypeID = ko.observable();
    self.EventTypeName = ko.observable();
    self.DepartmentID = ko.observable();
    self.DepartmentName = ko.observable();
    self.EventDescription = ko.observable();
    self.EventDate = ko.observable();
    self.EventItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.MembersAttended = ko.observableArray();
};

self.EventToAdd = new Event();
self.EventToAdd.EventName = 'test';
self.EventToAdd.EventItems.push(new EventItem(4));
```

I am getting that push is undefined.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `var self = this;` as the first line in your `Event` method.  Without it, you are accidentally adding all of the properties to your container object instead of to your `Event` object.